# Cut function creates too many levels

Tags: r, cut

I have a list of integers that represent years of education:

```
education= 12 14 17 15 12 19 16 12 16 14 12 18 12 13 18 18 10 13 12 18
22 16 13 22 12 15 12 16 18 18 18 20 18 16 13 12 16 13 18 20 20 20 14 18 
18 12 18 16 20 18 14 16 19 12 12 11 13 13
```

I am trying to categorize the years into 3 different levels:

9-12
13-17
18+

I have tried to used the cut function:

```
edulevels=cut(education,c(9,12,13,17,18,22))
```

but it creates 2 additional levels for 12-13 and 17-18:

```
Levels: (9,12] (12,13] (13,17] (17,18] (18,22]
```

How do I get it to only create these three levels?

Comment: The breaks are points in between factor levels. In your 3 different level example, you don't consider the space greater than 12, but less than 13, right? Maybe redefine how your levels are structure (`edulevels <- cut(education, c(9,12,17,Inf))` or something like that)?

Comment: So you want Levels: (9,12) (13,17) (18,22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest solution

```
edulevels=  cut(education,c(9,12.5,17.5,22), labels = c("9-12", "13-17", "18+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Intervals defined by the `cut()` function are closed on the right.  To see what that means, try this:

```
cut(1:2, breaks=c(0,1,2))
# [1] (0,1] (1,2]
```

As you can see, the integer `1` gets included in the range `(0,1]`, not in the range `(1,2]`. It doesn't get double-counted, and for any input value falling outside of the bins you define, `cut()` will return a value of `NA`.

When dealing with integer-valued data, I tend to set break points **between** the integers, just to avoid tripping myself up.

```
edulevels <- cut(education, 
   c(8.5, 12.5, 17.5, Inf),
   labels=c('9-12','13-17','18+')
   )
```